# Fatal error: Class 'DB' not found

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help with my coding. I have installed a software on my website. I know a bit of coding, but I cant solve this problem.

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'DB' not found in /home/a3042821/public_html/core/common/SettingsData.class.php on line 28

This is the code on line 28:

```
$all_settings = DB::get_results($sql);
```

Can I please get some help with this one? I have tried to search the internet, but I didnt find any answer.

Thanks :)

Comment: You have to check if you are loading the class. Check the installation manual (if you have anything like that) to see where the classes should be (i.e., where the software is reading the files from). Sort of assume that the DB class is from PEAR.

Comment: Where exactly is your `DB` class? From where you're calling this `get_results()` function?

Comment: The class i based in folder ezdb/ezdb.class.php

Comment: Is it [this database class](https://github.com/nshahzad/ezdb/blob/master/ezdb.class.php)?  If you placed in in `ezdb/ezdb.class.php`, did you include/require that file in this script or another file included by this script?

Comment: No i didnt. But when i try to require, I end up with a error that says "No such file in directory", but I am sure i have used the correct code: "require_once('./classes/ezdb/ezdb.class.php')" at the top of the file i get the error from.

Comment: Since you use the period first in your path are you sure the directory 'classes' is in the same directory as the script you are running?